# Dynamically I need to do binning based on Total capacity, In AWS TimestreamDB- query editor

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

Here is the SQL code :

```sql
WITH total_site_capacity AS (
SELECT DISTINCT(split(SiteName, '-')) AS sitename, SiteName, ProjectName 
FROM "telemetrydb"."30LogIntervalTelemetry" 
WHERE time >= (bin(current_timestamp,1day)-7d)-4h AND SiteName LIKE 'GS%'
),
totalcapacity AS (
SELECT SUM(IF(CAST(sitename[2] AS INT) = 220,200,CAST(sitename[2] AS INT))) * 0.8 * 0.75 AS total, SiteName, ProjectName
FROM total_site_capacity 
GROUP BY SiteName, ProjectName
) 
SELECT ROUND(SUM(pv.total),2) AS Cap, pv.ProjectName AS ProjectName, CONCAT(FLOOR(pv.total*0.15),'-', FLOOR(pv.total*0.3)-1) AS CapacityBin 
FROM totalcapacity pv 
JOIN totalcapacity AS cv ON cv.SiteName = pv.SiteName
GROUP BY pv.ProjectName, CapacityBin HAVING CapacityBin <> '' ORDER BY pv.ProjectName, CapacityBin
```

I am getting this error on this code:
line 14:3: Unexpected parameters (double, varchar(1), double) for function 'CONCAT'. Expected: CONCAT(array(E), E) E, CONCAT(E, array(E)) E, CONCAT(array(E)) E, CONCAT(varchar) , CONCAT(varbinary)

I have a total capacity(cap) for each site, Now I want to 7-8 bins for each site as 15% of cap(bin size) say 0-15%, For example if the cap is 300, 15% of 300 is 45 then it should be 0-45 as the bin name and so and so forth
`